# onCreate() not found in MainActivity.java

Tags: react-native, firebase-analytics

I am trying to integrate the Google Firebase Analytics in my react native project by referring to this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start?authuser=0

I have successfully integrate my project to firebase and it works fine but I got stuck when trying to add the analytic which is to initialize the `mFirebaseAnalytics`.

Based on the doc, I need to initialize it in `onCreate()` method but there is no such method found in my `MainActivity.java`. So I tried to code it myself.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
}
```

I stopped the integration until here. Then, when I run my project I got this error in my log.

> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED C:\Users\AA\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\MainActivity.java:39:
> >     error: cannot find symbol
> >         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> >                                 ^   symbol:   class Bundle   location: class MainActivity 1 error
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I guess I cannot add it manually in there. So what is the correct way to add it in?

Comment: try making `onCreate` public instead of private!

Comment: @JaydeepGalani The error is still appearing even after changing it to public.

Comment: is this imported ?
`import android.os.Bundle;`

Comment: Oh thanks, it's working now after I import it.

Comment: can you document what way of adding it worked in the end. maybe as an answer to your question?